# Accessing data from DLL

Tags: c#, dll, autoit

I have some working Autoit code, that I would like to implement in C#.
It reads a string from a DLL as shown below.

Autoit code

```
Func getAxQDLink()
    Local $axQdlink = ObjCreate("AxQDLink.AX_QDlink")
    If IsObj($axQdlink) Then
        $patInfo = $axQdlink.ContentXML
        MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, 'Test',$patInfo)
    EndIf
EndFunc
```

I have tried this in

C# code

```
    private void testQDOC()
    {
        Type axQdlinkType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("AxQDLink.AX_QDlink");
        dynamic AxQDLink = Activator.CreateInstance(axQdlinkType);
        string patInfo = AxQDLink.ContentXML;
        
        MessageBox.Show(patInfo);

    }
```

No Exception when run, but this can be found in the watch window:

> Message   "Error reading type DLL. (Exception  HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))"

So, any advice?

EDIT: The error seems to come in the GetTypeFromProgID method:

> GenericParameterAttributes    '((System.RuntimeType)axQdlinkType).GenericParameterAttributes' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'   System.Reflection.GenericParameterAttributes {System.InvalidOperationException}

Edit2: Visual Basic can access the DLL like AutoIT does

Comment: Is axQdlinkType null? What does the messagebox shows?

Comment: No, the Type is not null. The messagebox shows an empty string.

Comment: I have temporarily solved my problem by writing a small program in Visual Basic that reads data through the DLL, then transfers the data to my C# program